# Ambiguous column name error in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please see the following query.

```
select UserStatus,UserStatus from ((Select 'Active' as UserStatus) 
 union (Select 'Inactive' as UserStatus))a order by UserStatus
```

Error:

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'UserStatus'
```

Solution:

```
ALTER DATABASE VCarePortal
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100

90 = SQL Server 2005`enter code here`
100 = SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2
110 = SQL Server 2012.
```

I tried about compatibility level mode. but still i'm getting ambiguous error.

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: what is your expected result. do you want both columns or a signle column also ok?

Answer (score 2):

Please remove one UserStatus and try:

```
select UserStatus from 
(
    (Select 'Active' as UserStatus) 
    union 
    (Select 'Inactive' as UserStatus)
)a order by UserStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting the same column twice, remove one and that fixes the issue. You don't need that twice anyway as each of the selects that are unioned has only one column returned.

```
select UserStatus from ((Select 'Active' as UserStatus) 
 union (Select 'Inactive' as UserStatus))a order by UserStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ambiguity generate while you order the same column, so sql engine does not understand which column need to ordered.

So use below query will resolved your problem.

```
-- Order by 1 means order with first column in selection
select UserStatus, UserStatus 
from (
(Select 'Active' as UserStatus) 
 union 
 (Select 'Inactive' as UserStatus)
)a order by 1 


-- Or remove duplicate column from selection.
select UserStatus
from (
(Select 'Active' as UserStatus) 
 union 
 (Select 'Inactive' as UserStatus)
)a order by UserStatus
```